# Error in default table creation in Jboss7.xfor Http session persistance for mysql

Tags: java, mysql, http, jboss7.x, infinispan

I tried saving http session in mysql db using cache container in Jboss7.x. I am getting error

I have tried with oracle DB also, same issue.I am getting the below issue.

ERROR [org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.OracleTableManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 70) ISPN008011: Error while creating table; used DDL statement: 'CREATE TABLE "sess_AppzillonAdmin_war" (ID VARCHAR2(500) NOT NULL, DATUM BINARY NOT NULL, VERSION NUMBER NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (ID))': java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00902: invalid datatype

```
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:440)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIoer.processError(T4CTTIoer.java:396)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.processError(T4C8Oall.java:837)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.receive(T4CTTIfun.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CTTIfun.doRPC(T4CTTIfun.java:191)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4C8Oall.doOALL(T4C8Oall.java:523)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.doOall8(T4CStatement.java:193)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CStatement.executeForRows(T4CStatement.java:998)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.doExecuteWithTimeout(OracleStatement.java:1315)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdateInternal(OracleStatement.java:1822)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatement.executeUpdate(OracleStatement.java:1787)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeUpdate(OracleStatementWrapper.java:280)
at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedStatement.java:430)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.AbstractTableManager.executeUpdateSql(AbstractTableManager.java:124)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.AbstractTableManager.createTable(AbstractTableManager.java:117)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.AbstractTableManager.start(AbstractTableManager.java:56)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore.initializeConnectionFactory(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:426)
at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore.start(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:103)
at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:154)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.lambda$invokeAccessibly$0(SecurityActions.java:91)
at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.doPrivileged(SecurityActions.java:83)
at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.invokeAccessibly(SecurityActions.java:88)
at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:165)
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:859)
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:628)
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:617)
at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:542)
at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:238)
at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:862)
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:635)
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:585)
at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:451)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:108)
at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:103)
at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheBuilder.lambda$build$0(CacheBuilder.java:83)
at org.wildfly.clustering.service.SuppliedValueService.lambda$new$0(SuppliedValueService.java:42)
at org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalValueService.start(FunctionalValueService.java:68)
at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder.lambda$start$0(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:99)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

This change in standalone-ha.xml for persisting http session data in DB

```
<cache-container name="web" default-cache="jdbc_store" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
              <local-cache name="jdbc_store" >
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                    <string-keyed-jdbc-store data-source="ServerDS" dialect="MySQL" shared="true"  passivation="false" preload="false"  purge="false" fetch-state="false" singleton="false" />
                </local-cache>  
            </cache-container>


[org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.MySQLTableManager] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 69) ISPN008011: Error while creating table; used DDL statement: 'CREATE TABLE `ispn_entry_AppzillonAdmin_war` (id VARCHAR NOT NULL, datum BINARY NOT NULL, version BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))': com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL, datum BINARY NOT NULL, version BIGINT NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (id))' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1053)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2788)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1816)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.executeUpdate(StatementImpl.java:1730)
    at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrappedStatement.executeUpdate(WrappedStatement.java:430)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.AbstractTableManager.executeUpdateSql(AbstractTableManager.java:124)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.AbstractTableManager.createTable(AbstractTableManager.java:117)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.table.management.AbstractTableManager.start(AbstractTableManager.java:56)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore.initializeConnectionFactory(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:426)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.jdbc.stringbased.JdbcStringBasedStore.start(JdbcStringBasedStore.java:103)
    at org.infinispan.persistence.manager.PersistenceManagerImpl.start(PersistenceManagerImpl.java:154)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.lambda$invokeAccessibly$0(SecurityActions.java:91)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.doPrivileged(SecurityActions.java:83)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.SecurityActions.invokeAccessibly(SecurityActions.java:88)
    at org.infinispan.commons.util.ReflectionUtil.invokeAccessibly(ReflectionUtil.java:165)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry$PrioritizedMethod.invoke(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:859)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.invokeStartMethods(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:628)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.internalStart(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:617)
    at org.infinispan.factories.AbstractComponentRegistry.start(AbstractComponentRegistry.java:542)
    at org.infinispan.factories.ComponentRegistry.start(ComponentRegistry.java:238)
    at org.infinispan.cache.impl.CacheImpl.start(CacheImpl.java:862)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.wireAndStartCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:635)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.createCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:585)
    at org.infinispan.manager.DefaultCacheManager.getCache(DefaultCacheManager.java:451)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:108)
    at org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.DefaultCacheContainer.getCache(DefaultCacheContainer.java:103)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi.service.CacheBuilder.lambda$build$0(CacheBuilder.java:83)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.service.SuppliedValueService.lambda$new$0(SuppliedValueService.java:42)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.service.FunctionalValueService.start(FunctionalValueService.java:68)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.service.AsynchronousServiceBuilder.lambda$start$0(AsynchronousServiceBuilder.java:99)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

Comment: Which version of the application server is this exactly? Can you please get the exact version of Infinispan being used ?

Comment: Application server is Jboss-eap-7.1 and infinispan:4.0

Comment: Infinispan version: Infinispan 'Chakra' 8.2.8.Final-redhat-1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed standalone-ha.xml cache-container configuration as below it works fine.
data-source="MYSQL1.5" we have to give the pool name defined in data-source configuration

```
 <cache-container name="web" default-cache="jdbc_store" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
            <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
          <invalidation-cache name="jdbc_store1" mode="ASYNC">
                <string-keyed-jdbc-store data-source="MYSQL1.5" dialect="MYSQL" fetch-state="false" passivation="false" preload="false" purge="false" shared="true" singleton="false">
                    <string-keyed-table prefix="sess">
                        <id-column name="ID" type="VARCHAR(500)"/>
                        <data-column name="DATUM" type="longtext"/>
                        <timestamp-column name="VERSION" type="BIGINT"/>
                    </string-keyed-table>
                </string-keyed-jdbc-store>
            </invalidation-cache>
</cache-container>
```